# How to observe edits for items using NSTreeController and NSOutlineView

Tags: objective-c, nsoutlineview, nstreecontroller

I have an `NSOutlineView` populated using an `NSTreeController`. The tree controller manages an array of `NSMutableDictionary` with properties including: `NSString *name`, `and NSArray* children`.

How do I get a notification when `name` has changed in the UI?

Answer (score 0):

just put a function into delegate of NSOutlineView

```
- (BOOL)control:(NSControl *)control textShouldEndEditing:(NSText *)fieldEditor
{
    // for example that is checked that node text is not empty
    if ([[fieldEditor string] length] == 0)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else
    {
        return YES;
    }
}
```